# Too many arguments to method call expected 1, have 2

Tags: ios, objective-c

That look silly, but i cant figure out why is there an error:

```
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.get?access_token=%@", self.secret]];
```

And XCode warn me with "red" error - Too many arguments to method call expected 1, have 2. But i dont have second `"%@"` symbol, why is that happen?

Comment: `URLWithString:` doesn't take two arguments.  You passed a formatting string and `self.secret`.

Comment: Read the class reference for `NSString`.  You'll find what you need there.

Comment: Don't use compound statements, they get to long and hard to debug, comprehend and understand quickly. Use intermediate statements with temporary statements. Write code to be read by developed, not the compiler.

Comment: @zaph thank you for advice, that will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking the statement into intermediates allows pinpointing errors and is easier for developers to quickly understand. There should be no performance penalty, the compiler will combine the statements.

Also use a version of the API that provides error feedback.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.get?access_token=%@", self.secret];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&error];
if (data) {
    // process data
}
else
    NSLog(@"data error: %@", error);
    // handle error
}
```

Yes, error handling is messy and a PITA but really does need to be done, that is a part of software development.

Note: this web access will block the app until it  completes, it is better to use async methods that do not block.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban This is the answer you should accept. It's fine to change which answer you accept. This answer is so much more helpful than the other one (which is correct too). People need to emulate this sort of answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.get?access_token=%@", self.secret]]];
```

you should create formatted string with `stringWithFormat:`